# Error writing data to a native process from an air application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I am writing an AIR application through which I want to open a native process 'wordpad.exe' and write data generated in the AIR application to a document.

My code is as follows:

```
   import flash.desktop.*;
   import flash.errors.*;
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.filesystem.*;
   import flash.utils.*;

   var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo=new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
   var executablePath:String="C:/Program Files/Windows NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe";
   var str:String="Hello";
   var file:File=new File(String(executablePath));
   nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable=file;
   var process=new NativeProcess();
   process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
   process.standardInput.writeUTF(str);
```

The wordpad application opens with a blank document but it generates an error
Error#2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:.text=Error #3128: Error while writing data to  NativeProcess.standardInput.

and nothing gets written in the wordpad document.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out @MartinL's comments in [this conversation](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-245156.html). Similarly, I don't think WordPad can be managed using StdIn/StdOut, which means you can't pass it inputs using AIR's `NativeProcess` API.

However, you could write a C# console application that serves as a piece of light middleware, which you *could* open with `NativeProcess`, submit inputs via StdIn, and which would relay your inputs into WordPad. The .Net framework has a [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) that can do this, though some light research left me with a sore impression of it.

While this should work, it sure sounds like a kludge. Could you optionally create a new .rtf file, populate it with text, then programmatically open the new file using AIR's [FileSystem.openWithDefaultApplication()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication%28%29) method?